# Make findfile() always return full path

Tags: filesystem

While I was answering another question, I noticed an odd behaviour in the functions `finddir()` and `findfile()`.  According to the help page, both of these functions will return the full path to the first match *unless* the match is found in a directory beneath the specified directory.  Is there some way of forcing both of them to return a full path?

Comment: Call `fnamemodify(..., ':p')` on the results?

Comment: AFAICT, you can not with current implementation of `findfile()`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I'll accept that if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Then you'd be wrong to do it.  A real answer would have to distinguish between `finddir()` / `findfile()` returning a string, and returning a list. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is impossible to force `findfile()`/`finddir()` to return full paths, but it is possible to convert them to full paths using the `fnamemodify()` function.  It takes two arguments: the path you want to modify, and the modifiers.  In this case, the modifier we are interested in is the `:p` modifier.  This will take the given path and convert it to a full path.  This can then be used on the outputs of the `findfile()` and `finddir()` functions, though it is a little trickier since we must account for the fact that they may return a list instead of just a string.  Here is the solution I have come up with:

```
" Use ... to capture any and all arguments passed to this function
function! FindFileFP(...)
    " Use the call function to call a function with all of the captured arguments
    " as arguments to the specified function.
    let result = call(findfile, a:000)
    " Check to see if the result is a list
    if type(result) == type([])
        " Apply the fnamemodify function to every item in the list
        map(result, 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":%p")')
    else
        " Otherwise, just set the variable to the result of fnamemodify
        result = fnamemodify(result, ':%p')
    endif
    return result
endfunction
```

Note that you can create a counterpart for the `finddir()` function by simply changing all references to `findfile()`.

For more help, see `:help fnamemodify()` and `:help filename-modifiers`.

**NOTE:**

There may be a shorter way of doing this, improvements welcome.